# How many levels of pipelining can be acomplished with modern CPUs vs GPUs?

Tags: assembly, gpu, cpu, cpu-architecture

I red in [these slides](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~crawfis/cse786/ReferenceMaterial/CourseNotes/Modern%2520GPU%2520Architecture.ppt) that GPUs typically have much deeper pipelining than CPUs.

> GPUs have much deeper pipelines (several thousand stages vs 10-20 for
>   CPUs)

I would like to find more numbers but tried googling and wasn't able to find any. I noticed this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) noted that the Pentium 4 prescott was deeply pipelined.

Qualitatively speaking, how is it that pipelining can have more than 3 levels? Considering the fetch/decode/execute cycle, that's only 3 things? Is it that there's multiple functional units, for example there are more than 1 decoders so more than 1 instruction can be decoded at a time? How can more than 1 thing be red from memory at once?

Please remember to include numbers regarding levels of pipelining in your answers.

Comment: Lots of instructions take more than one execute cycle, and operand fetch may require several steps by itself.

Comment: And back in 1971 I worked on a CPU with two adders and a dual-ported register set.  Many systems have the adder and shifter as separate units, not to mention those that have dedicated multiply/divide units.

Comment: Pipeline length is a matter of throughput versus latency.

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea how Professor Crawfis is getting thousands of pipeline stages for GPUs. While GPUs generally have high latency for dependent operations (on the order of 22 cycles), this is partially due to not making results available as soon as they are calculated (i.e., no result forwarding) and partially because of the processing of a block of SIMD-like operations in a sequence of suboperations (typically four suboperations, so each only needs to be a quarter as wide). Unfortunately, details on GPU microarchitecture are hard to find.

An example of a moderate-length pipeline might help make clear how a pipeline can be longer than a few stages. The MIPS R4000 (introduced in the early 1990s) had an eight-stage pipeline for simple integer operations:

1. Instruction (fetch) First stage: Access to the instruction cache is started
2. Instruction (fetch) Second stage: Access to the instruction cache is completed
3. Register File access: the instruction is decoded, the register file read, availability of operands is confirmed, and the instruction cache hit is confirmed (It was possible to delay this because the instruction cache was direct-mapped [only one choice] and a hit is speculatively assumed. On an instruction cache miss, three cycles of work would be flushed [similar to the handling of a branch misprediction].)
4. EXecution: the branch target or address for a memory access is calculated, the condition for a branch is evaluated, or a computation is performed (or at least started, multiplication and division take multiple cycles; e.g., 10 cycles for 32-bit multiplication)
5. Data (access) First stage: Access to the data cache is started
6. Data (access) Second stage: Access to the data cache is completed
7. Tag Check: The data cache tags are checked to confirm a hit. (Because the data cache is also direct-mapped, a loaded value can be speculatively forwarded to execution so that a dependent operation only needs to wait two cycles instead of three.)
8. Write Back: The result of an operation is written to a register

In *theory*, just like an assembly line, each unit of work can be divided into smaller units of work. However, like in an assembly line, finer division can reduce throughput even though the number of workers increases. (Imagine an assembly line in which each stage makes one turn of a screw. While this would allow many screw-turners to work on a single screw, the overhead of inserting and removing the screwdriver would make this very inefficient. Latch and other overheads have a similar effect in processor pipelines.) Unlike traditional industrial assembly lines, processor pipelines also must deal with changes, a branch misprediction might be *vaguely* analogous to a change in assembly procedure which is improperly communicated to the workers; the problem might not be recognized until the quality control inspector sees the problem and the entire assembly line needs to be stopped, all the defective partially assembly products removed, and the line restarted with proper procedures in place.

For more modern examples consider the following:

- AMD's Jaguar (in the Playstation 4 and the XBox One) has 14 stages from start of fetch to writeback for simple ALU operations: Fetch0, Fetch1, Fetch2, Decode0/Fetch3, Decode1/Fetch4, Decode2/Fetch5, iDecode, Pack, FDecode, Dispatch, Schedule, RegisterRead, ALU, WriteBack (Load operations replace ALU with AGU and add Data Cache1 and Data Cache2 stages; FP/SIMD operations add Transit, FPDecode, and an additional RegisterRead stage) (from David Kanter's [Jaguar article](http://www.realworldtech.com//jaguar/))
- Fujitsu's SPARC64 X has 18 stages for memory operations: 4 fetch stages; 4 decode and issue stages; 5 dispatch, register read, and execute stages; 3 stages for L1 Dcache access; and 2 commit stages (from page 11 of the 2012 Hot Chips presentation [SPARC64 TM X: Fujitsu’s New Generation 16 Core Processor for the next generation UNIX servers](http://jp.fujitsu.com/platform/server/sparcenterprise/event/12/hotchips24/pdf/HotChips24_Fujitsu_presentation.pdf))
- Intel's Poulson (Itanium 9500 series) has 11 stages for simple integer operations and loads (single cycle L1 cache with direct register addressing): Instruction Pointer Generate, Instruction Fetch, Front-end Decode, Register Rename, Instruction Buffer and Dispersal, Instruction Decode, Register Access, Instruction Execute, Detect Exceptions, Writeback Commit, Writeback-2 Retire (from Figure 2-4 Back-End Pipeline Control Mechanisms in [Intel Itanium Processor 9500 Series Reference Manual: Software Development and Optimization Guide](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/itanium/itanium-9500-reference-manual.html))
- Intel's Silvermont (new Atom) has 14 stages for simple integer operations: three instruction fetch stages, three instruction decode stages, two allocate/rename stages, one schedule stage, one execute stage, two retire stages, and two commit stages (from David Kanter's [Silvermont article](http://www.realworldtech.com/silvermont/))

Note that all of these modern microarchitectures have buffering between some stages, so instructions do not simply flow through the pipeline or stall as in simpler pipeline designs. In addition, some operations take more than one cycle to execute and some operations may not be fully pipelined.

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's start from the end:

> How can more than 1 thing be read from memory at once?

It always is. A processor with a 64 bit data bus doesn't read a byte at a time from memory, it reads eight bytes at a time. Besides, decoding instructions isn't limited to only one memory read.

> Is it that there's multiple functional units, for example there are
>   more than 1 decoders so more than 1 instruction can be decoded at a
>   time?

Some processors may have some parallel processing for that, but it doesn't have to be. There is just so much time for the processor between memory reads that it can decode several instructions in the time until the next memory read can be done.

The limiting factor for the pipeline in a processor is really that the execution jumps back and forth in the code. If the code would always run in sequence, then the pipelines could be very long. The processor tries to predict where the execution will be going, but any prediction that is wrong makes the rest of the work done in the pipeline useless.

The code that the graphics processors executes is a lot more math and lot less jumping around, so they can make use of a lot longer pipelines.

Comment: "If the code would always run in sequence, then the pipelines could be very long." But why, I mean, if the pipeline was just 3-segments, branch prediction would be no issue (just throw away 2 segments). Why is there a need for longer pipelines?

Comment: @Caramiriel: The long pipelines allows the processor to execute several instructions each clock cycle. It's no longer limited to doing one thing, then wait for the next clock cycle to start doing the next thing. This is why current Intel processors are 100.000 times faster than the original 8086 processor eventhough the clock speed is not even 1000 times higher.

Answer (score 1):

Fetching from memory takes longer that one clock cycle, [reporting otherwise assumes access from core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546756/does-a-one-cycle-instruction-take-one-cycle-even-if-ram-is-slow).

For example the NVIDIA CUDA (Tesla) GPU data is processes using 32 threads called a warp, [you will see that](https://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v2n1a5.htm)

> When the threads in a warp issue a device memory operation, that instruction will take a very long time, perhaps hundreds of clock cycles, due to the long memory latency.

So if memory fetch takes hundreds of cycles, then pipelining can keep the processor busy executing.